# Can annotation processor be used for code generation?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say I define an annotation called `@MyAnnotation`.

There is a class `X` which is declared as:

```
@MyAnnotation
class X { .... }
```

Now at compile time I want to inspect all classes annotated with `@MyAnnotation` and do some code generation to more java source files that need to be compiled as well in the same process.

Is this possible using java annotation processor or some other tool?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html. Take a look here. It is possible.

Comment: That's what annotation processing is for. You're basically asking if it can do what it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may take a look at the Java `apt (Annotation Processing Tool)` for such a thing.

You can find the [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) page, and a nice article ([1](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/), [2](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/), [3](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/annotation-generators/))  about how to use that to generate code.

Comment: `warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.`

Answer (score 16):

APT tool has been merged into javac in Java 6. [This](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/) is a much better tutorial for annotation processing.